# WorldClim bioclimatic data extraction in R: NAs obtained

Tags: raster, r, coordinates

I've been trying to extract bioclimatic variables from WorldClim based on a lat-long data frame. I've successfully obtained the RasterStack but when trying to extract the variables from a subset of coordinates ('coords' object in the code), I obtained a lot (but not all) of NAs. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Here is my code:

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
r <- getData("worldclim",var="bio",res=2.5)
r <- r[[c(1,4, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17)]]
names(r) <- c("Temp", "Temp_seasonality", "Temp_warmest_q","Temp_coldest_q","Prec", "Prec_seasonality", "Prec_wettest_q", "Prec_driest_q")
```

`coords` looks like:

```
          [,1]     [,2]
  [1,]  14.650   40.350
  [2,]  13.600   39.350
  [3,]   0.033  -78.717
  [4,]  37.017   -2.383
  [5,]  46.837 -113.966

dim(coords)
[1] 421   2

points <- SpatialPoints(coords, proj4string = r@crs)
values <- extract(r,points)
```

`values` df has a lot of rows with NAs, although some of them do have the bioclimatic variables.

Comment: Did you plot results? Probably are out of valid data

Comment: I did. The problem had to do with the fact that the columns of 'coords' were reversed as indicated by Spacedman below. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your coords are:

```
          [,1]     [,2]
  [1,]  14.650   40.350
  [2,]  13.600   39.350
  [3,]   0.033  -78.717
  [4,]  37.017   -2.383
  [5,]  46.837 -113.966
```

but coordinate matrices are always X then Y, ie Longitude then Latitude. Your NAs are coming from column 2 being more than 90 or less than -90, which are not valid latitudes.

`extract(r, coords[,2:1])` should be sufficient to flip the column order (you don't really need to construct a spatial points object because `extract` is flexible).

Comment: It worked with extract(r, coords[,2:1]). Thank you very much!